# React Native tabbar flickering

Tags: ios, react-native, uitabbarcontroller

I have used React native native base library for Tabbar with 4 screens but it is flickering while switch tabs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, Tab, Tabs } from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabOne';
import Tab2 from './tabTwo';
​export default class TabsExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header hasTabs />
        <Tabs initialPage={1}>
          <Tab heading="Tab1">
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab2">
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading="Tab3">
            <Tab3 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add any one of the Tab content code, `Tab1` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I developed an app as well in react-native. The problem for me was that I had used componentsWillUpdate for animations. Instead I did a helper function for the animations.

Don't know how the rest of your code looks like but this solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can be here that you want to

1, Install: [switch-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/switch-react-native)

```
npm i switch-react-native
```

2, Using lib:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Switch } from 'switch-react-native';
 
class SwitchExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Switch
          height={40}
          width={300}
          activeText={`Active Text`}
          inActiveText={`InActive Text`}
          onValueChange={(value: any) => console.log(value)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```